# Como recorrer un objeto JSON con arrays anidados?

Tags: javascript, json

quiero hacer una función que devuelva un array que contenga los nombres de las personas (en cualquier orden) que disfrutan del hobby.
    Por ejemplo, el siguiente código debería devolverme el nombre "Adam","Mary".

```
var hobbies = { "John": ['Piano', 'Puzzles', 'Yoga'], 
                 "Adam": ['Drama', 'Fashion', 'Pets'], 
                 "Mary": ['Magic', 'Pets', 'Reading'] }; 

 console.log(findHobbyists(hobbies, 'Pets'));
```

Mi idea es esta:

```
function findHobbyists(hobbies,srt){

  let personas = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < hobbies.Adam.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < hobbies.Mary.length; j++) {

           const elementAdam = hobbies.Adam[i];
           const elementMary = hobbies.Mary[j];


       if((elementAdam && elementMary) === srt ){

        personas.push("Adam");
        personas.push("Mary");
      }

    } 
  }
  return personas;

  }
   console.log(findHobbyists(hobbies,'Pets'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findHobbyists(hobbies, srt) {
  return Object.keys(hobbies).filter(
    (name) => hobbies[name].includes(srt)
  );
}
```

Esta función regresa un array con los nombres que buscas

Comment: Muchas gracias :)